# Reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I have the equation $$x^2 y'' + (2x^2 - 3x) y' + 3y = 0$$ and the solution $$y_1 = x^3 e^{-2x}$$ Using reduction of order: $$y_2 = v y_1$$ I reduced the equation to $$v'' x^5 + v' x^4 = 0$$ so $v(x) = \ln x + C$. However, I thoroughly checked $$y_2 = x^3 e^{-2x} \ln x$$ and it does not work in the original equation. Any suggestions?

Comment: You made a mistake somewhiere.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 y'' + (2x^2 - 3x) y' + 3y = 0$$
$$ y''+2y'-3 \dfrac {( x y' - y)}{x^2} = 0$$
$$y'+2y-3\dfrac y x=C_1$$
$$ {y'}-y(\dfrac 3 x-2)=C_1$$
$$\left( ye^{-\int(\dfrac 3 x-2)}\right)'=C_1e^{-\int(\dfrac 3 x-2)}$$
$$ \left( y\dfrac {e^{2x}}{x^3}\right)'=C_1\dfrac {e^{2x}}{x^3}$$
$$ y\dfrac {e^{2x}}{x^3}=C_1 \int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{x^3} dx+C_2$$
$$ y(x)= {e^{-2x}}{x^3} \left(C_1 \int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{x^3} dx+C_2 \right)$$
The intergal can't be calculated with elementary functions.

Comment: You integrated the exponent in the integrating factor incorrectly. The answer is x^(-3) e^(2x), not x^(-3) e^(-2x). Also you solved for y incorrectly. You should have multiplied by x^3. As I stated in the problem above, the function y = x^3 e^(-2x) is a solution to the ODE.

Comment: Correced thanks. But still the integral cant be computed with elementary functions @KenM

Answer (score 0):

If $y_(x)$ is a solution of $y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$ then it otther solution is given by
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int \frac{e^{-\int P(x) dx}}{y_1^2(x)} dx$$
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x) \int \frac{e^{\int (-2+3/x) dx}}{x^6e^{-4x}}$$
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x) \int \frac{e^{-2x} x^3}{x^6e^{-4x}}dx$$
$$y_2(x)=y_1(x)\int \frac{e^{2x}}{x^3} dx=y_1(x) e^{2x}\left[\frac{-1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{x}\right]+2y_1(x) \text{Ei}(2x).$$

EDIT: Yes instead of $\text{Ei}$ it should be leftas $\int \frac{e^{2x}}{x}dx$

Comment: Yes this is the Frobenius series solution (which is derived using reduction of order), but why does normal reduction of order not work? Also, y_1 = x^3 e^(-2x), which simplifies your solution a bit. Doesn't the Ei function have an infinite limit of integration?

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right I have edited it now.